# custom time interval for geowebcache

Tags: geoserver

How to assign time interval to take regular cache using geowebche. For instance every afternoon at 13:00 hrs geowebcache should be started automatically and it should start creating tiles. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a complete working method to seed tiles automatically with GeoWebCache:

1) Go to http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/, select your Operating System, and then download and install the cURL utility.

2) Then, with the help of cURL you can initiate a seeding task:

```
curl -v -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<seedRequest><name>WORKSPACE:LAYER</name><srs><number>4326</number></srs><zoomStart>1</zoomStart><zoomStop>12</zoomStop><format>image/png</format><type>truncate</type><threadCount>2</threadCount></seedRequest>" "http://127.0.0.1:8090/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/WORKSPACE:LAYER.xml"
```

[image]\

- **Notice 1**: Pay attention to the text capitalisation, especially when you use a workspace with uppercase letters, like mine; otherwise you'll obtain an error.
- **Notice 2**: In Windows, you'll obtain an other error if you will try to run the example showed in [GeoWebCache REST API Seeding and Truncating](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/rest/seed.html) (In Windows, you must use only double quotes in the curl command).
- **Notice 3**: Don't use breaks in the curl command if you are not looking for troubles.
- **Notice 4**: Between the `type` tags you can use the `seed / reseed` or `truncate` methods.

3) In Windows, all you have to do, is to schedule a new task for the seeding process:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

4) And here's your tiles:

[image]

Comment: where the xml file will be saved and how to add that in task ?

Comment: You don't need to create or save the xml file. The cURL utility will generate a seed/reseed/truncate task request in xml format, which will be automatically sent to the GeoServer.

Comment: So I should point the windows task scheduler to curl.exe ? Am I right ?

Comment: I've updated my response.

Comment: Călinicăis there any way to use bounding box option in curl tool?

Comment: If you'll follow the link in my **Notice 2** you'll see a more complete XML fragment for a seed request, including the bounds coordinates.

Comment: Using the bounds coordinates, the seeding task will be something like this: curl -v -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<seedRequest><name>WORKSPACE:LAYER</name><srs><number>4326</number></srs><bounds><coords><double>-2495667.977678598</double>      <double>-2223677.1962315</double><double>3291070.61042868</double><double>959189.33124650</double></coords></bounds><zoomStart>1</zoomStart><zoomStop>12</zoomStop><format>image/png</format><type>truncate</type><threadCount>2</threadCount></seedRequest>" "http://127.0.0.1:8090/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/WORKSPACE:LAYER.xml"

Answer (score 4):

You could try setting up a cron job if you are running on a Linux system.

Comment: I am using windows !!

Comment: @Vikram: so that sort of information might have been useful to include in the question. Please consider that for next time.