# Caching Updated Data with GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I have a PostGIS database that gets updated about once every two hours. Since Geoserver datastore do not do any caching, I was looking for service does that and i found GeoWebCache REST API http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/rest/seed.html

from what i understand, its the only option for caching updated (new) data. am i right? and is there any detailed example on how to apply it?

I am using openlayers, with wms

Comment: Maybe this information will help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87728/custom-time-interval-for-geowebcache/87804#87804

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
GeoWebCache is what you are looking for.

Make sure you truncate the cache for that layer everytime you update the back-end data.
You might want to do a selective (with BBOX) truncate via REST interface.

Check these links:
http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.5.1/rest/seed.html#seeding-and-truncating-through-the-rest-api
https://github.com/geosolutions-it/scripts/blob/master/geowebcache/gwc_truncate.sh

The latter was used to automate truncate via bash scripts with CRON in the mix. Might be helpful.

Simone.