# How to tell if GeoWebCache REST API is working?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, web-mapping, geoserver-rest-api

In my web application, i wanted a service to cache updated data using geowebche. so i worked on seeding tiles automatically with GeoWebCache as in this post:
[custom time interval for geowebcache](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87728/custom-time-interval-for-geowebcache/87804#87804)

then i replaced `wms` with `gwc/service/wms` in layer requesting in OpenLayers. i didn't do anything more than what's in the post. here it said i have to install the extinction but i didn't. http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/installation.html#rest-installation

Now, how can i tell if it works? do the tiles get refreshed by themselves without me refreshing the page or what?

and I use WMS to display my points on the map, is there any way to cache the layer where it doesn't need to reload points whenever i navigate on the map?

Comment: I'm not sure an API can be said to be working or not working.  You should be able to test that the calls you're making to the REST service are working by using something like curl.

Comment: yes that's how i made it, but not sure how to tell if it's working!

Answer (score 1):

When a request is handled by GeoWebCache, it adds some [custom headres to the response](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/responseheaders.html)

Check the http requests with firebug to see in the headers if the following header is present in the response:

> geowebcache-cache-result: HIT