# Bounding Box in CuRL Tool(REST API)

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, curl

I have set my time interval using CuRL tool for automatic [Geowebcache](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87728/custom-time-interval-for-geowebcache).. How to set bounding box in curl command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documented in GeoWebCache manual http://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/rest/seed.html

Here is an example about REST seed request in json format. I hope it helps. Note the non-standard gridset.

```
curl -v -k -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{'seedRequest':{'name':'GWC_layer','bounds':{'coords':{ 'double':['3200000.0','7000000.0','3300000.0','7100000.0']}},'srs':{'number':2393},'zoomStart':8,'zoomStop':11,'format':'image\/png','type':'seed','threadCount':4}}}" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/GWC_layer.json"
```